# WebPageContent problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, nsstring

I have parsed some data from webpage content and stored it as an NSString. In that string there is a unicode character (\u0097). How can i remove or replace this and avoid all unicode characters?

I tried using this line but it hasn't worked:

```
[webpagecontent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u0097" withString:@" "];
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: Cleaned up question and retagged, since this question is about strings and unicode, and not anything specific to iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no escape sequence that is legal C (`\u0097` is not) and works in GCC. You'll have to use `stringWithFormat:` or `stringWithCharacters:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "avoid all unicode characters" you could probably make an NSCharacterSet that contains everything except ASCII characters (you would want -[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:]), then use -[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:] and -[NSMutableString deleteCharactersInRange:] to remove the characters.